# How to dump a hung process that is already being debugged

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugger

When debugging my program, the program intermittently hangs, together with the debugger (Windows, Visual Studio, .NET). When this happens, it seems impossible to get a dump of the process in any  way (tried command line, process explorer, task manager). Attempting a dump also blocks. Presumably because dumping a process is similar to debugging it, and a debugger is already attached?

Stopping or detatching the debugger in Visual Studio is not possible, it never detatches/stops. Killing the debugged program with taskkill is normally possible however.

I'm guessing that something in the debugger/debuggee processes deadlocks on some global mutex or similar. But how would I find out where it happens? I'd like to get dumps of the both the debugger and debugged programs, in order to see the call stacks of all threads, but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what a thread is doing usibg
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Locate the process, double-click it to get into Properties, then position to the
Threads tab.

You will see what the thread are doing. Click on one thread and use the Stack button
to see what the thread is doing.

A pretty good knowledge of Windows is required to analyze a program this way.